# Recent Apache DOS advisory - problem applying the SetEnvIf/ RequestHeader workaround

Tags: apache-2.2, security

so one of the mitigations for this advisory was:

1) Use SetEnvIf or mod_rewrite to detect a large number of ranges and then
   either ignore the Range: header or reject the request.

Option 1: (Apache 2.0 and 2.2)

```
      # Drop the Range header when more than 5 ranges.
      # CVE-2011-3192
      SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1
      RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range

      # optional logging.

      CustomLog logs/range-CVE-2011-3192.log common env=bad-range
```

Now when I add this to my httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
SetEnvIf Range (,.*?){5,} bad-range=1
RequestHeader unset Range env=bad-range

</IfModule>
```

I get this error when restarting Apache:

"Invalid command 'RequestHeader', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

The SetEvnIf module seems to be loaded.

What is wrong with that parameter?

Version is Apache/2.2.14 .

Link to the advisory is: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-announce/201108.mbox/browser

also, would Tomcat be vulnerable to this?

tia!

Comment: If in Ubuntu, `sudo a2enmod headers` should fix it.

Answer (score 9):

`RequestHeader` requires you to load [`mod_headers`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader)

Answer (score 1):

as per DerfK's answer, you need to load mod_headers -- a la

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

in your conf file before the call to RequestHeader